# $scope is not updated in Modal after second $scope change in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I've been breaking my head for a long time with this but I can't find the solution. Please check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfGZr/4/). If you click into the box, a list of categories appears. Then if you select a value, it's copied to `categoryFilter` through

```
$scope.categoryDropDownClickEvent = function(value) {                   
        $scope.categoryFilter = value;
        console.log($scope.categoryFilter);
    };
```

Then if you erase it and select it again, it doesn't work anymore though the scope itself is updated (see console). How come?

Comment: I think it has sonething to do with javascripts prototypal inheritance. Instead of using `categoryFilter`, try inserting a dot in the name. Try to create an object of categoryFilter. Something like `$scope.categoryFilter.name`

Comment: @Martijn pfffff finally [it works!](http://jsfiddle.net/XfGZr/12/) Thanks man! If you put it as an answer i'll accept it.

Comment: Glad I could help. Not so long ago I had the same issues :) The important thing to remember is: always use a dot in your model!

Comment: @Martijn true, i'll definitely remember that now hahaha could you update your fiddle with [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/XfGZr/16/) where the textfield issue is solved as well?

Comment: I've updated the link in my answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made an update to your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XfGZr/16/). Basically what I've done is created an object on the scope variable:

`$scope.filter.name`. I think that the problem you're experiencing has something to do with scope inheritance. `ng-repeat` creates a new scope for every iteration.